# Adding and Removing Additional Documents with Roslyn

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, roslyn

I have two code refactorings, one that amongst other things, generates a csv file and adds it to the Project in the solution, and another that is supposed to edit it.

I am successfully (seems like it, it shows in the solution explorer after it) generating and attaching the csv file to the solution Project through the code:

```
var doc = editor.GetChangedDocument();
SourceText st = SourceText.From(csv.GetStringDocument(), Encoding.Default);
var additionalDoc = doc.Project.AddAdditionalDocument(filename, st, new List<string> { "_TestData" });
return additionalDoc.Project.Solution;
```

Before returning, if I check additionalDoc.Project.AdditionalDocuments.Count(), its' value is 1.

And, in the other, when I try to access the additional files in the Project, the IEnumerable is empty.

How is it supposed to access the additional documents added with code refactorings/code fixers?

Comment: It's a reported bug. You can follow the issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4655